# Is there a way to use Aurora Postgres 14.3 from CDK?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, amazon-aurora

If you look at the AWS Console, Aurora Postgres-compatible version 14.3 is available to be provisioned.  [image]

However, it looks like the [latest version available in CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_rds/AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.html#aws_cdk.aws_rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion) is 13.7.

Is there a way to manually pass in 14.3 when instantiating a cluster from CDK?

```
rds.DatabaseCluster(
            self,
            'AuroraPostgresCluster',
            engine=rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.aurora_postgres(
                version=rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_13_7
            ),
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes.
I would try the static `of()` [Method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.html#static-ofaurorapostgresfullversion-aurorapostgresmajorversion-aurorapostgresfeatures), but You have to know also the `auroraPostgresFullVersion` Parameter.

Start with

```py
rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.of('14.3', '14.3')
```

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Updates.Versions.html#AuroraPostgreSQL.Updates.Versions.EngineNumber) states:

> Starting with PostgreSQL 10, PostgreSQL database engine versions use a
> major.minor numbering scheme for all releases. Some examples include
> PostgreSQL 10.18, PostgreSQL 12.7, and PostgreSQL 13.3.

So in my opinion this should work, however I didn't tried this out.

Answer (score 0):

It is now available:

```py
engine=rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.aurora_postgres(version=rds.AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.VER_14_3)
```